# How to send a message with specific offset to EmbeddedKafka in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test, embedded-kafka

I am writing an integration test for an application that connects to Kafka to consume and publish data and for that purpose I am using EmbeddedKafka. Part of the logic is to consume messages with specific offsets. I want to simulate this, therefore my goal is to:

1. send some messages to EmbeddedKafka, but with specific offsets
2. consume them with the same offsets

This doesn't work now, i.e. I'm sending messages with `KafkaHeaders.OFFSET`, but it's ignored, the message that I'm consuming afterwards has a different offset. In fact the offset just starts with 0 and is then incremented.

```
MessageBuilder<String> messageBuilder = MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload)
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, topic)
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, key)
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID, partition);
        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET, val);
kafkaTemplate.send(messageBuilder.build());
```

`KafkaTemplate<String, String>` is initialised in a standard way. On the other end I consume in a standard way:

```
private class MessagesWithOffsetsConsumer implements BatchMessageListener<String, String>, ConsumerSeekAware {

    MessagesWithOffsetsConsumer() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records) {

        records.forEach(record -> {
            String id = record.key();
            String dataAssetPayload = record.value();
            int partitionId = record.partition();

            LOGGER.info("Received record: {} offset: {}", id, record.offset());
    }
}
```

In short, offset of a message received in `onMessage` is not the same as set during message building.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no something like an explicit offset value on the `ProducerRecord`.
You only can set these props:

```
public class ProducerRecord<K, V> {

    private final String topic;
    private final Integer partition;
    private final Headers headers;
    private final K key;
    private final V value;
    private final Long timestamp;
```

And that's really what is done from the `KafkaTemplate` logic. The `KafkaHeaders.OFFSET` is a consumer side property:

```
public class ConsumerRecord<K, V> {

    private final String topic;
    private final int partition;
    private final long offset;
    private final long timestamp;
    private final Headers headers;
    private final K key;
    private final V value;
```

In other words: Apache Kafka is not designed for an explicit offset setting.